# How does a program control hardware?

Tags: operating-system, hardware

In order to be executed by the cpu, a program must be loaded into RAM. A program is just a sequence of machine instructions (like the x86 instruction set) that a processor can understand (because it physically implements their semantic through logic gates).

I can more or less understand how a local instruction (an instruction executed inside the cpu chipset) such as 'ADD R1, R2, R3' works. Even how the cpu interfaces with the ram through the northbridge chipset using the data bus and the address bus is clear enough to me.

What I am struggling with is the big picture.

For example how can a file be saved into an hard disk?
Let's say that the motherboard uses a SATA interface to communicate with the HDD. 
Does this mean that this SATA interface has an instruction set which can be used by the cpu by preparing SATA instructions written in the correct format?

Does the same apply with the PCI interface, the AGP interface and so on?

Is all the hardware communication basically accomplished through determining a stardard interface for some task and implementing it (by the companies that create hardware chipsets) with an instruction set that any other hardware components can query?

Is my high level understanding of hardware and software interaction correct?

Comment: I think generally your understanding is correct, except I think it's not always as simple as the processor communicating directly with each device. For instance, a processor may communicate with a UART device, or some other device, that in turn communicates with memory or the network or monitor etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART for an example. More generally, modern computing hardware setups involve DMA as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly. It's actually more general than an instruction.

Alot of these details are architecture specific, so I will stick to a high level general overview of how this can be done.

The CPU can read and write to RAM without a problem correct? You can issue instructions that read and write to any memory address. So rather than try to extend the CPU to understand every possible hardware interface out there, hardware manufacturers simply map sections of the address space (where RAM normally would be) to hardware.

Say for example you want to save a file to a hard drive. This is a possible sequence of command that would occur:

1. The command register of the hard drive controller is address 0xF00, an address that is outside of RAM but accessible to the CPU
2. Write the instruction to the command register that indicates we want to write to the hard drive.
3. There could be conceivably an address register at 0xF01 that tells the hard drive controller where to save the data
4. Tell the hard drive controller that the data I want to write is at some address in RAM, and initiate the write sequence.

There are a myriad of other ways this can be conceivably be done, but the important thing to note is that it is simply using the instructions that the CPU already has for using RAM.

All of this can be done by the CPU without any special instructions on the CPU side, just read and write to an address. You can imagine this being extended, there is a special place in the address space for the USB controller that contains a list of USB devices, there is a special place for the PCI device list, each PCI devices has several registers that can be read and written to instruct them to do things.

Essentially the role of a device driver is to know how these special registers are to be read and written, what kind of commands devices can accept, etc. Often, as is the case with many graphics cards, what these registers do is not documented to the public and so we rely on their drivers to run the cards correctly.

Comment: Thank you. You described the memory mapped i/o (which I knew), but you added some details that I were missing. So these device drivers know the correct format to be issue to the physical device (because hardware vendors programmed them). When the OS is loading a driver, it just has to allocate some memory area for the mapping into ram (I guess this is accomplished dynamically) and inform the device controller (in the device chipset) about the area of memory that it should check. It can do that because the ram address bus is shared. I got it right?